# ignoring last value if its the same as current value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an table where i would like to query the following:

The data comes in batches . This data is combined with an id.

This ID only gets send ones when the new batch comes in. After that the ID only changes when there is a new batch . In the mean time the value stays null

What i need to do is if new data comes in and it has the same id as the previous batch i have to continue the insert with null in the id field instead of pushing a new row with the same id value.

Beneath is a simplistic view of the table

```
ID            Values
1             10
null          20
null          20
null          20
null          20
2             20
null          20
null          20
null          20
null          20
1             20
null          20
```

If you could help me point in a directions that would help me a lot.

Maybe to clearify the id value is a set of tags. So there are some definied tags(100 or more) and when a new batch comes the batch gets a tag with it. And if that tag is the same as the previous the null has to continue instead of inserting the same tag

Comment: Select max id from the table and compare it with the incoming data? Or select max of some other column that defines order and where id is not null.

Comment: Remember that data is stored unordered. If you want a specific order, you've got to do ORDER BY, and also have a sequence or timestamp column or similar.

Comment: The data is stored and ordered  by data and its a sql server

Comment: Maybe to clearify the id value is a set of tags. So there are some definied tags(100 or more) and when a new batch comes the batch gets a tag with it. And if that tag is the same as the previous the null has to continue instead of inserting the same tag

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an identity field (or a timestamp) in order to be able to query the latest ID.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyIdent INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
```

Then on your insert (if your Id value is NULL) you can call

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Values) 
   SELECT TOP 1 Id, @ValuesVariable 
   FROM MyTable 
   WHERE Id IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY MyIdent DESC
```

Comment: In that case you only need the 2nd part of the answer. Just order by your timestamp field desc instead.

Comment: Maybe to clearify the id value is a set of tags. So there are some definied tags(100 or more) and when a new batch comes the batch gets a tag with it. And if that tag is the same as the previous the null has to continue instead of inserting the same tag

Answer (score 0):

This below Sp may helps to inert data try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID INT,[Values] INT)

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Insert 
(
@Id INT,
@Values INT
)
AS
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp(ID,[Values])
    SELECT @Id,@Values
END  
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO #Temp(ID,[Values])
    SELECT NULL,@Values

END


EXEC usp_Insert 2,12

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```